# Distance between distributions of different mass

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to compare distributions but most of the definitions I can find assume that the distributions have the same total mass. Are there more or less standard ways, such as some generalization of the Wasserstein distance, to compare distributions of different mass?

Comment: Have you tried Kullback-Leibler distance?

Comment: Most of the time I find the ``$\chi^2$- distance'' (I don't know a more classical name right now) $$\mathrm{dist}_{\chi^2}(P_0,P_1)=\int\left( \frac{\mathrm{d}P_1}{\mathrm{d}P_0}(x)\right)^2 \mathrm{d}P_0(x)-1$$ quite useful, but it's also defined for probability distributions (It looks ugly, but plug in continuous densities or point masses and it gets better)... I'm curious, what kind of distribution doesn't have total mass 1?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am actually looking for distances that are not just point-wise but that take into account some transport cost. My distributions are areas of geometric shapes, that's why they are of different mass.